# nested view controllers, where to add subview and how to manage memory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have one root viewcontroller loaded by app delegate and a second one (no nib file) that should be loaded as root controller's child (i want to display its view contained in root controller's view).
Where and how should i do this? Is viewDidLoad method suitable for such initialization?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
MyViewController* pdfController = [[MyViewController alloc]init];
[self.view addSubview:pdfController.view];  
[super viewDidLoad]; }
```

What about releasing such an object? Should I release it in dealloc or viewDidUnload or both? where viewDidUnload/dealloc will be called?

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is an okay place to add your child view to the root view.  You should release it at the end of viewDidLoad; pdfController will be going out of scope (so you'll be losing track of the object) and [UIView addSubview:] will retain it.  If you were also keeping a reference to pdfController in an object property, you would want to release it in dealloc for that object.